# VAR model coeffiecients in all lags

Tags: vector-autoregression

When analyzing the results of a VAR model with 12 lags, should i take care for the coefficients of all 12 lags, or should i only look up for the coefficients of the last (12) lag?

Comment: What do you want to do with these coefficients?

Comment: I mean, when i am interpreting the coefficients in the analysis. Should i explain the coefficients in the other lags, or only the last lag?

Comment: VAR coefficients do not have clear interpretations, unless it is a structural VAR model. It is easier to interpret impulse response functions and forecast error variance decomposition instead. But in general, all lags are equally important.

Comment: This was very helpful. Thank you for the clarification Richard.

Comment: See also [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/40905/arima-model-interpretation/63072#63072) which applies not only to ARIMA but also to VAR.

Comment: Thanks again. And when it comes to interest rate, does it matter if in the model they are included as percentage, or a number divided by 100 (ex. 4.3% od 0.043)?

Comment: That does not matter for estimation, but you have to interpret the results accordingly.